# How to do no indentation on next paragraph? (`\noindent` only work on this paragraph)

Tags: indentation

I want to create a macro for section type that starts with a date. I have gotten this far:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setsecheadstyle{\Large\scshape\memRTLraggedright}

\newcommand{\dateSection}[2]{\section*{#1}{\vspace{-1\baselineskip}\hfill \small #2}\noindent}

\begin{document}
\dateSection{Lorem ipsum}{Monday Mars 21}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

but I get an indentation after it and the `\noindent` I have added does not help me.

[image]

What can I do to fix this in the macro?

Comment: Is the date supposed to be on the same line as the section title, or below it? With `\vspace{-1\baselineskip}` it will probably bump into any title that is longer. Anyway, you are looking for the internal command `\@afterheading` (use `\makeatletter before your definition).

Comment: Plan is to have it like this (bumping) for now until I find a title that is too long (I think all titles I need to support are short), then I will have to adopt :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up the next paragraph to gobble the indentation box.

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setsecheadstyle{\Large\scshape\memRTLraggedright}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dateSection}[2]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  {\vspace{-1\baselineskip}\hfill \small #2\par\nobreak}%
  \@afterindentfalse % don't indent the next paragraph
  \@afterheading % don't break pages too early
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\dateSection{Lorem ipsum}{Monday Mars 21}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

This way it's irrelevant whether you have a blank line or not after the `\dateSection` command.

There will be at least two lines of the next paragraph together with the section title and the date.

[image]

Comment: I suppose I have to upvote you for posting the right answer :(

Comment: Note that `\@afterindentfalse` sets the flag that `\@afterheading` checks before preventing (removing, actually) the indentation.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `\raisebox` in your macro definition:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setsecheadstyle{\Large\scshape\memRTLraggedright}

\newcommand{\dateSection}[2]{\section*{#1\hfill\raisebox{-0.6\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\upshape\small#2}}}

\begin{document}

\dateSection{Lorem ipsum}{Monday Mars 21}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It seems the second argument messes things up, I don't know for which reason, so I proposed this workaround.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I redefined the command using `\raisebox` and I obtain the same result, but I now can have a blank line. Do you think this code is correct?

Comment: yes making the date thing be part of the heading so coming before the "following paragraph" code is the other reasonable approach (I'll delete these comments in a bit)